# Export and import data using openair

Tags: r

I used `rbind` to create a column like:

```
datall.txt<-cbind(date, gpcp, modens, arp, miroc, gfdl, had, ccc, ncc, ich)
```

`head(datall.txt)` give the below results:

```
      date      gpcp   modens      arp    miroc      gfdl      had      ccc      ncc      ich
1   1981-01-01 0.2348780 0.469833 0.277215 1.023630 0.3910260 0.427785 0.613363 0.414251 0.141564
2   1981-02-01 0.4107710 0.702776 1.097940 1.260230 0.3892770 0.710179 0.676518 0.399144 0.386144
3   1981-03-01 1.4685400 1.236660 1.095350 2.350400 0.7050500 1.521330 0.977459 0.912380 1.094660
4   1981-04-01 2.0427100 2.169680 1.638580 3.846270 1.7133000 1.940160 1.702460 1.927560 2.419450
```

I would like to use this created file and when I import it I am having fie don't exist

```
mydat<-import("/Users/sarr/rcatxt/datall.txt")
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/Users/sarr/rcatxt/datall.txt': No such file or directory
```

How can I get this file or what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not creating a `.txt` file, just an R object called `datall.txt`. It could just as easily been named `datall` and R would treat it the same.

To actually create a file use `write.table()`:

```
write.table(cbind(date, gpcp, modens, arp, miroc, gfdl, had, ccc, ncc, ich), file = "datall.txt", row.names = FALSE)
```

This will create a file in your active working directory.

Then to import it back into R using the `openair` package as you would like:

```
mydat <- openair::import("/Users/sarr/rcatxt/datall.txt", sep = " ", date.format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: The write.table created the file and solved the first part of the problem: Now to import the file I need a function named import (openair package) when I use I get ths error message which look strane because date is in the file. Any other hint?

Comment: output from import:  mydat <- import("/Users/sarr/rcatxt/datall.txt")
Error in import("/Users/sarr/rcatxt/datall.txt") : 
  Can't find variable date

Comment: Have you tried adding a format string for your dates: `mydat <- import("/Users/sarr/rcatxt/datall.txt", date.format = "%Y-%m-%d")`? (or `"%Y-%d-%m` if day of month comes before month.)

Comment: still the same error: mydat <- import("/Users/sarr/rcatxt/datall.txt", date.format = "%Y-%m-%d", sep="\t", fill=TRUE)
Error in import("/Users/sarr/rcatxt/datall.txt", date.format = "%Y-%m-%d",  : 
  Can't find variable date

Comment: I just updated my answer. If it still doesn't work, could you show us what your new `datall.txt` file looks like?

Comment: It still does not work. If think import can't read the header because if i put header=F it don't ask for date but names: I don't knot how to attach a sample file but I created 1: The data look like this                               "date" "gpcp" "modens" "arp" "miroc" "gfdl" "had" "ccc" "ncc" "ich"
"1" 1981-01-01 0.234878 0.469833 0.277215 1.02363 0.391026 0.427785 0.613363 0.414251 0.141564
You have date, observation and 7 models values. I want a Taylor Diagram from openair and to first import the data. Thank you again for your assistance. I can send you a sample if necessary

Comment: Yes please PM me the file.

Comment: I don't where I can attach file because don't takes a limited number of characters

Comment: Do you know how I can send you the file?

Comment: here I am having an error: Date conversion problems, check that date.format is correct ? Did you manage to open the file I sent you?

Comment: Yes I got the file. Did you redo the `write.table` line with the updated `rownames` parameter? I changed that too.